# French for “milk” as in “milk the situation for money”?

Tags: vocabulaire, choix-de-mot

What is the usual French way for saying 'milk' of the verb, not the noun? For example, in order to say like belows to criticize a boss's greediness toward money and profits?  Thanks for any input. "You blindly follow your boss's order, and for what, so they can just milk the situation for money".

Comment: I know the verb traire which has a similar feeling as milk, cf. https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/traire, second meaning: Dépouiller financièrement.

Answer (score 1):

Considering that the verb "milk" in English often refers to an intellectually dishonest manner in which one tries to extract the maximum financial (or otherwise) gain from a given situation over an extended period, how about:

> Tu obéis à ton chef au doigt et à l'œil. Et ce, uniquement pour qu'ils puissent **s'en enrichir** / **s'enrichir** **toujours plus**.

I might go for « tirer le meilleur parti d'une situation » in a different context, but as you seem to be talking specifically about monetary gain here, this phrase would sound rather vague, falling short of conveying the *monetary*  nuance.

Ideally, if I could replace « s'enrichir » with its more casual counterpart, more in keeping with the informal tone of the verb "milk".

Comment: *S'enrichir* is fine but *s'en enrichir* is slightly odd. Here is a couple of more casual/colloquial alternatives of *s'enrichir*: *s'en mettre plein les poches* and *se gaver*.

Comment: @jlliagre Hi. As for "s'en enrichir", does it refer more to some enhancement in a positive sense? I wasn't sure about this, so I placed them both. If this is the case, please feel free to edit it out accordingly. :)

Comment: No big deal. I just wouldn't have written *Pour qu'ils puissent s'enrichir toujours plus de ce que tu obéisse à ton chef au doigt et à l'œil*. Who is *ils* is also unclear.

Comment: @jlliagre Ah, I see. What I had in mind (as to what "en" refers to) was more like "*Pour qu'ils puissent s'enrichir toujours plus **d'une situation fructueuse***", supposing that the word "situation" or something similar was used in the preceding context. As for "ils/they", perhaps the OP refers to ***several*** big shots in the organisation, including the boss?

Comment: I guess another possibility is the OP used a singular *they*.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the closest French expression is “tirer profit de [la situation]”, in which “tirer” (“draw”) is used similarly to “milk”. This expression can be used in formal language. I can't remember any slang variation to it.